# Does there exist a smooth version of Cohen's factorization theorem?

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis

A famous factorization theorem of Cohen states that for any locally compact group $G$, $$L^1(G)=L^1(G)*L^1(G).$$
I want to know if analogous results exist for the class of smooth functions when $G$ is a Lie group. For instance, is it true that
$$C^\infty(G)=C^\infty(G)*C^\infty(G)?$$

(Feel free to impose any simplifying assumption such as compactness of $G$, compactly supported functions, or
$$C^\infty(G)=\text{Span } C^\infty(G)*C^\infty(G)$$ 
etc.)

It would be great if someone could point out some of the known positive or negative results or open problems that might exist. References are also highly appreciated.

**Added in Edit**:

1. While browing the web, I came across the [thesis](http://ediss.uni-goettingen.de/bitstream/handle/11858/00-1735-0000-000D-F074-7/palm.pdf?sequence=1) of Marc Palm, where he mentions on page 65 that

> Every smooth function is the convolution product of smooth functions,
>   briefly denoted by $$C_c^\infty(G)=C_c^\infty(G)*C_c^\infty(G).$$

This is clearly stronger than the D-M result, and in contrast, in my opinion, to what Paul writes below in the comments:

> A technical point is that finite sums are necessary in that context,
>   so not every test function is exactly a single convolution of two.
>   Does Marc really mean $C_c^\infty(G)=\text{Span }C_c^\infty(G)*C_c^\infty(G)$?

2. I also came across [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124260/trace-class-functions-on-locally-compact-groups) by Marc Palm where he gives an answer to my question below (in the comments).

Comment: Isn't this exactly the Dixmier-Malliavin result?

Comment: @paulgarrett The version of Dixmier-Malliavin that I have in mind is (roughly) the following: "Every smooth vector in a Frechet representation $(\pi, V)$ belongs to the Garding space."

Comment: So the D-M result is not addressing some aspect of things relevant to your purposes? Yes, the D-M more directly addresses test functions, i.e., compactly-supported, not all smooth, but that's not a fatal problem. A technical point is that finite sums are necessary in that context, so not every test function is exactly a single convolution of two. Can you clarify your issue?

Comment: @paulgarrett You are absolutely right, D-M result is completely relevant to my question. My interpretation of D-M in this context is that any function in $C_c^\infty(G)$ can be approximated by a linear combination of the functions in $C_c^\infty(G)*C_c^\infty(G)$. Now I have two questions. (1) is this the right conclusion from D-M? (2) if the answer to the previous question is yes, then isn't the same conclusion clear from the fact that any function in $f\in C_c^\infty(G)$ can be approximated by $g_t*f$, where $g_t$ is an approximate unit? Sorry if these are too naive questions.

Comment: It's not only approximated, but _equal_. (The weaker and much easier "approximation" assertion is essentially Garding's from 1947 or so, which would also cope directly with approximation of smooth by convolutions). But then, in any case, you can certainly _approximate_ arbitrary smooth by test functions, if that's enough for you. To get exact equality with $C^\infty*C^\infty_c$ seems tricky... Is approximation good enough for you?

Comment: @paulgarrett D-M should be a strong positive result for many practical purposes. I just wanted to know what work has been done in this direction. As a separate question, does this follow from D-M that any function $f\in C_c^\infty(G)$ is a linear combination of the convolutions of the form $g*g^*$ in $C_c^\infty(G)*C_c^\infty(G)$? I think this is true but I don't have a reference for it. I really appreciate your help and clarification.

Comment: I don't really know about the latest on this. Bill Casselman has a nice essay about D-M and its proof on his web-site ... which probably you can find as quickly as I can. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett I was looking at the same essay:) but Casselman doesn't mention any "symmetric" factorization $g*g^*$ theorem there. Perhaps it is not to hard to see, but not very clear to me.

Comment: Not clear to me, either. The argument is not at all trivial, even after Casselman's discussion... Entire functions and such...

Comment: Yes, I forgot the span in the sentence, but the theorem does mention it. Sorry.